# How do i create a shop for a discord bot in python 3.6.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots

So i have created currency for a bot called "battlePoints" or bp for short. The problem is that I want to create a shop to buy items from (doesn't have to be stored) I got this so far but don't know how to make into a command like buy name.

```
items = {
    "Game1":[3,20],
    "Game2":[5,30],
    "game3":[5,20],
    "game4":[8,10],
    }
while True:
    print("game1 = 3BP / game2 = 5BP / game3 = 5BP / game4 = 8BP")
    print("Account Balance bp",stash)
    choice = input("What would you like to buy?: ").strip().title()
    if choice in items:
        if items[choice][1]>0:
            if stash>=items[choice][0]:
                items[choice][1]=items[choice][1]-1
                stash= stash-items[choice][0]
                print("Thank you..!")
                print("")
            else:
                print("Sorry you dont enough money...")
                print("")
        else:
            print("sorry sold out")
            print("")
    else:
        print("Sorry we dont have that item...")
        print("")
```

I've tried adding in `client.commmand()`
async def buy(): and then the code but i doesn't seem to work. 
Could you either point me in the right direction, show me where i can find the answer or could you please just tell me what i did wrong

Comment: Do you have a bot that is up and working, or are you trying to create one and this is all the code you have?

Comment: i have a bot up and running here is the link to the full code https://hastebin.com/qijajujogu.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the problem would be `choice = input("What would you like to buy?: ").strip().title()` as bots do not receive input via the `input()` function. You can typically pass the context of a message to your functions though. I see in your full code you have:

```
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
```

Where I will note `pass_context = True`. This lets your function read the context & contents of a discord message. For instance you can call `ctx.message.author` to get the author of the message that is being interpreted. So if say "Bob Joe" types "!clear 50" then:

```
ctx.message.author == "Bob Joe"
```

This should also change `amount` from 100 -> 50. Using similar techniques you can have a user "!buy GoldShoes" and it will trigger your `async def buy(ctx, item):` case where:

```
item == "GoldShoes"
```

It is then up to your logic to determine what to do with this input, but maybe this helps explain the process a bit. Let me know if I was unclear about something.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use `print()` and `input()`, there are different functions and modules there, you have to install and import discord, also import commands from `discord.ext`. then add `ctx` as a parameter in the command so you use `await ctx.send(message)`. you use `client.wait_for('message')`, its more like `input()`. I suggest you check out the docs for discord.py, its completely different from this.